# Browser opens play store when tried to load certain link

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

I just found that when I tried to visit certain page in firefox(also in the built in browser), it opened play store's page for a certain app which is related to the website.
The website I tried to visit was "flipkart.com" an the play store page was showing it's app. When I enter the link and pressed the button, ff says that "Couldn't find an app to open this link" and loads play store. Why it is so? 
Because of this, I can't visit that website

Comment: Sounds like they've got some kind of redirect in place because they want you to use their app instead. If they redirect all Android browsers to a `market://` link then it'll try to open the Play Store.

Comment: Some sites do that whenever they detect a "mobile client". A work-around is, if your browser supports it, to "request the desktop version" (or fake a corresponding user-agent string).

Comment: @Izzy I have requested the "desktop version", it works first, when I open another tab from the link in the page, it again goes to playstore. I have installed UC Browser but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I'm not aware of any real solution *you* could establish. If it's just one site, I'd recommend contacting their stuff. If they are not "cooperative", stop using the site – and tell them they'll lose visitors that way (like they've just lost you). Forcing visitors to a specific app is not the way to go. // An idea, though: Browsers like *Opera Mini*, which use a proxy to retrieve "compressed content", might be a possible alternative.

Comment: @Izzy Their reply was this: Thanks for writing to us. We at Flipkart are continuously striving to provide a smoother, faster and better experience for our customers and we strongly believe the Flipkart Mobile App guarantees that. We have full confidence that after trying the app, you would agree with us and enjoy great shopping experience. With that in mind, we have disabled our mobile site. Do write in to us in case you have more feedback.

Comment: Well, that leaves the alternative pointed out. Writing them "thanks, but there are people who don't want to install an extra app for each page on the Internet, and so you've just lost a long-term user." Plus some facts from above, if you feel like. They don't have to maintain a separate mobile page, but should not *force* mobile users to their app. Pointing to is fine, but then there should be an easy way to say "no, thanks" and get the "normal web page" instead. That would be the approach I'd take – and I know more people feel like that (from experience on other sites which rolled back then).